# Not all pantheon-files issues transfered to github

Tags: pantheon-files, github

There are some bugreports on launchpad that were not transfered to github issues ([this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+bug/1693030) for example). 
Were they filtered by some conditions or this is just a bug with transfer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that the tool that does the automatic import from Launchpad creates too many issues to fast and GitHub blocks it temporarily after a certain number.

However, we do not want to blindly import bug reports that are likely to be out of date, unconfirmed etc.  The rate at which bugs can be addressed is extremely limited.

It has been decided to manually import any remaining bountied bugs and close the Launchpad tracker now.  So any "live" bugs that have been missed will unfortunately have to be re-raised on GitHub.